# curve on animation tab (idk how to explain just look at the pic)

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, eevee-render-engine, graph-editor, timeline

Recently I downloaded blender 2.92 and when I already started animating, it always slows down towards the end like a curve. The picture I sent has this sort of like curved line on the animation and I'm unsure how to get rid of it. Does anyone know how to change it to like linear? It would be really helpful because I'm still new to this version, thanks.

[image]

Comment: if you mean the curved arrow -> this is just the symbol which says "yes, this object has an animation" - that's all. If you want linear animation you have to go to your timeline, tab V and choose linear. But this will not change the curved arrow ;)

Comment: still didn't work tho